# Host WebApiService

Tags: api, web-services

I am new to .Net web field. I want to be able to call my web Api service from other computers within local network or my office.

I can call my Api in my browser but other can't. My another PC is also able to ping this ip address.

Please guide me. I can't find any references. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found firewall is blocking, turning it off solve my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to disable the firewall. In most computers **port 8080** which you are using isn't open by default.Just make an **inbound rule** on your firewall to allow the connection. Something like below:[image]

Press next and check the `Allow the connection` option in the next screen and then try again.